# Spring Security 6 : can't access to secured method after authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, spring-security

After successful basic authentication (login/password in body) when I access to an other secured controller's method I have a 401 error.
I'm not sure but it seems the security context is not set.

Do you have an idea or a line of research?

**Use case with swagger**

1. call `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login` as admin => success and `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` has an authentication as `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`
2. call `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/me` => success. authentication is always `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` and the user admin is returned
3. call `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/distributors/isauthenticated` => failed and return a 401 http status.

**The step 3 logs**

```
2023-01-10 10:16:48,523 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping         : Mapped to fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.controller.DistributorsController#test()
2023-01-10 10:16:48,524 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  Spring Security Debugger                           : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/api/v1/distributors/isauthenticated':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5d0e637c

servletPath:/api/v1/distributors/isauthenticated
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0
accept: */*
accept-language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
referer: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
connection: keep-alive
cookie: JSESSIONID=F6F38EADC8BA2ADF82A519C33507D25F
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin


Security filter chain: no match


************************************************************


2023-01-10 10:16:48,524 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping         : Mapped to fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.controller.DistributorsController#test()
2023-01-10 10:16:48,524 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  : GET "/api/v1/distributors/isauthenticated", parameters={}
2023-01-10 10:16:48,524 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping         : Mapped to fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.controller.DistributorsController#test()
2023-01-10 10:16:48,524 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.a.m.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Authorizing method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public void fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.controller.DistributorsController.test() throws java.lang.Exception; target is of class [fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.controller.DistributorsController]
2023-01-10 10:16:48,525 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver    : Using @ExceptionHandler fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.resterror.RestExceptionHandler#handleAuthenticationException(AuthenticationException)
2023-01-10 10:16:48,526 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor   : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2023-01-10 10:16:48,526 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor   : Writing [fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.resterror.RestErrors@55eb7689]
2023-01-10 10:16:48,527 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver    : Resolved [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext]
2023-01-10 10:16:48,528 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  : Completed 401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

**Quick info**

- spring boot 3
- spring security 6

**Code**

```
package fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.DelegatingSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Autowired
  UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Bean
  public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
    return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
    return new ProviderManager(daoAuthenticationProvider());
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return provider;
  }

  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    HttpSessionRequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
    requestCache.setMatchingRequestParameterName("continue");
    // @formatter:off
    http
    .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
    .cors().and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .formLogin().disable()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)).and()
    .securityMatcher("/api/*/auth/**")
    .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz.requestMatchers("/api/*/auth/**").permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/me").permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers("/api/*/public/**").permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers("/api/*/catalogs/*/documents/*/file").permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers(req -> req.getRequestURI().contains("mail-images")).permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers(req -> req.getRequestURI().contains("api-docs")).permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers(req -> req.getRequestURI().contains("swagger-ui")).permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers(req -> req.getRequestURI().contains("h2-console")).permitAll()
                                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
    .authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())
    .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext.requireExplicitSave(false)) // Spring secu 5.8
    .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext.securityContextRepository(new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
      new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
      securityContextRepository()
    )))
    ;
    // @formatter:on

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

```
package fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.dto.LoginDto;
import fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.dto.UserDto;
import fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.exception.NotFoundException;
import fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.mapper.UserDtoMapper;
import fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.model.UserEntity;
import fr.gregoire.passpro.backend.service.UserService;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/auth", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class AuthenticationController {

  @Autowired
  private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  private UserDtoMapper userDtoMapper;

  @PostMapping("/login")
  public ResponseEntity<UserDto> login(@NotNull @Valid @RequestBody LoginDto loginDto, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    final Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDto.getLogin(), loginDto.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
      .setAuthentication(authentication);
    securityContextRepository.saveContext(SecurityContextHolder.getContext(), request, response);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.userDtoMapper.modelToDto((UserEntity) authentication.getPrincipal()));
  }

  @PostMapping("/logout")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
  public void logout() {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
  }

  @GetMapping("/me")
  public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getAuthenticatedUser() throws NotFoundException {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
      .getAuthentication();

    if (null == authentication || !authentication.isAuthenticated() || !(authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserEntity)) {
      throw new SessionAuthenticationException("UNAUTHORIZED");
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.userDtoMapper.modelToDto(this.userService.findById(((UserEntity) authentication.getPrincipal()).getId())));
  }
}
```

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/distributors", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class DistributorsController {

  @GetMapping("/isauthenticated")
  @Secured(RoleEnumConstants.ROLE_ADMIN)
  public void test() throws Exception {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
      .getAuthentication();
    System.out.println(authentication.getClass()
      .getCanonicalName());
    System.out.println(authentication.getCredentials());
    System.out.println(authentication.isAuthenticated());
    System.out.println(authentication.getDetails());
    System.out.println(authentication.getAuthorities());
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help and have a nice day,
Nicolas

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the `RestExceptionHandler#handleAuthenticationException` and check the cause of the `AuthenticationException`. What does it say? :)

Comment: The same as in the above logs : `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`

Comment: Why are you using authenticationmanager and dao authentication provider?

Comment: @YannickMussche I need a bean AuthenticationManager. If there is not,spring boot does not start. I have already made some attempts of code before. This is the last.  Before I used ```@Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
  }``` whith the same result

Comment: @YannickMussche `.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())` is an other attempt. Without this code there is the same result

Comment: I've struggled to with getting the new Spring working, But I managed to get the authentication done with the bean you mentioned in the comment. I couldn't get my authentication inside the authorizeRequest so  I did it outside.

Comment: I'm only struggling with the role recognisition, rest works, you can find my code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74951295/how-to-setup-preauthorize-with-spring-security-5-7, It migt help you to get the authentication done

Comment: @YannickMussche your link is sending to a 404 page